# want to know how view(static function) runs behind the scenes in Route::view('/','home');

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**i found static view function as**

```
public static function view(
$uri,
$view,
$data = [],
$status = 200,
$headers = []) {  //nothing here but getting view }
```

> we have passed $uri='/' and $view='home' ,it is not returning anything but we are getting view. how this is possible?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#view-routes)?

Comment: yah but how we get view from view method because it is not returning anything,it is just accepting arguments and there are no statements inside this method.

Comment: I don't really get what your question is, tbh. The documentation explains exactly what the method does. It's just a convenient way of showing a specific view on a specific route, so you don't need to manually make a controller and return the view yourself. I'm guessing it will actually call the [ViewController](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/ViewController.php) in the background.

Comment: yes it's a shortcut way of displaying view which is mentioned in documentation. apart from that i would like know how we are getting view behind the scenes.

Comment: Check the ViewController I linked to. Specifically the line `return $this->response->view($view, $data, $status, $headers);`. As you can see in https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/ceb3217fa65e9cfb7ca8287f5e2aca11467fd8a1/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L265, it uses that ViewController.

Comment: Where/how did you find that? Is that an interface? https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php has all router methods